# Function as a series :

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$. Verify that
$$\int_0^xf(x)dt=f(x)-1$$
This is the exercise 3 of the section $7.4$, of Guidorizzi's Calculus, Vol. 4.
What I have tried:
By the ratio test, $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ converges. So, $\forall x\in\Bbb{R}$, $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ is a real (constant) number. Then
$$\int_0^xf(x)dt=[f(t)t]_0^x=xf(x)-0f(x)=xf(x)$$
So I have tried to make some computation, but I cannot see how $xf(x)$ could be equal to $f(x)-1$.

Comment: It should be $\int_0^x f(t)dt$.

Comment: For each $x$, $f(x)$ is a constant --- but not the same constant for each $x$! That is, $f$ is not a constant function.

Comment: Anderson, you have edited your question to write $$\int_0^x f(x) \, dt \text{ instead of } \int_0^x f(t) \, dt.$$ Are you sure about this?

Comment: Thanks guys. But I think that was really an typing error of the book. Surely the correct is $\int_0^x f(t)dt$ but there is $\int_0^x f(x)dt$.

Comment: Due to this I said that $f(x)$ is a constant. Surely it is not, saw as a function of $x$, but it is as a function of $t$. But the statement of the exercise is surely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First way:**

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x.$$

Then, $$\int_0^x f(t)dt=\int_0^x e^t dt=\left[e^t\right]_0^x=e^x-e^0=e^x-1=f(x)-1.$$

**Second way:**

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
converge uniformly (to $e^x$, but this is not the problem), then you can permute limits and integral. Therefore,
$$\int_0^x f(t)dt=\int_0^x \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!}dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^x \frac{t^n}{n!}dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}-1=f(x)-1.$$

Q.E.D.

Comment: Thanks! I was really supposed to do the second way ^_^. I cannot use yet that $\sum_0^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$

Answer (score 0):

You should use the fact that the sum is uniform convergent in the interval and substitute the sum and integration.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding power series. The function $f$ is not constant.

What you have to do is integrate term by term, apply the fundamental theorem of calculus and rewrite the resulting series conveniently in order to transform the expression in something in terms of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$f(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} $$

Thus $$ \int\limits_0^x f(t) dt = \int\limits_0^x \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \int\limits_0^x\frac{t^n}{n!}.$$

Can you take it from here?